# Silverlight MediaElement Bitrate

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, smooth-streaming

I'm developing a custom player (s) for Silverlight, one based with `MediaElement` and other with `SmootStreamingMediaElement`. For the moment I'm using the latest version of the SDK 5.0 but I would like to support previous versions once all my issues are resolved.

All is working fine (playback) and now I've got a basic understanding about the platform and APIs, but I'm stucked with a (non) trivial feature: I want to get the Bitrate information for the current playing video, no matter if its a single bitrate or multibitrate file... must work on both cases.

As far as I know I have the following properties and methods for the `MediaElement` API that are useful but not enough: `DownloadProgress` and `BufferProgress`. No method for getting the Bitrate or similar information found in the specification except `TotalBytesDownloaded` property for `SmoothStreamingMediaElement` Class.

Using the MediaElement and `SmootStreamingMediaElement` APIs is possible to get the average or instant bitrate of a video file?

If not, there is any workaround to handle it?

Do I have access to `MediaItem` (from within a `MediaElement` instance) in order to get some more information about the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `MediaElement` class doesn't have such functionality. But you can detect the current bitrate by using the more advanced `SmoothStreamingMediaElement` class.

Here is a msdn article that explains how to use this class: [Select and Monitor Bitrate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182017%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

The complete code that watchs the current bitrate:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    media.PlaybackTrackChanged += OnPlaybackTrackChanged;
}

void OnPlaybackTrackChanged(object sender, TrackChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Current bitrate: " + e.NewTrack.Bitrate.ToString());
}
```